# iOS - time out exception when downloading multiple images

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

First of all, let me explain what I do. I need to plot some hundred annotations on `MKMapView` with image. My client has provided a SDK which gives me nearly 100 objects which I should display on Map.

This is how I get the items from my SDK

```
SDKRequest.Request(request) { (items, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Update UI
            })
            }.execute()
    }
```

Each item has properties like title, id, image, etc. To get the image, SDK has an API

```
item!.loadImage(/*desired size*/) { (image, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                // Update UI
            })
        }
```

I get nearly 100 items and to download the image associated with the item, I run a for loop. When all 100 requests to download images are sent in one shot, after downloading approximately 30-40 images, I get request time out exception.

On successful image download, I set the image to the respective annotation and I add that to Map. Finally, I end up resulting in adding only 30-40 items on map (out of 100).

To solve this, I can make it as an recursive function which is not a genuine idea.

So, to handle this condition, how would I regulate this multiple downloads, the best way?

Answer (score 0):

To download the 100 images and store it is not the good idea. You can do it by caching also. You can display thumbnail image until image download. You can easily achieve it by `AFNetworking+UIImageView` category and there are other classes available for the same. It will do the same if image url is already requested and it's cached then it won't download again and gives you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best implementation to be sending a request per image without some kind of a throttle mechanism. That could be a reason for your time out exception.

**Dispatch Semaphores** work pretty well for bulk. Dispatch Semaphores call down to the kernel only when the calling thread needs to be blocked. If the calling semaphore does not need to block, no kernel call is made.

Apple Developer Library - [Dispatch Semaphores](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW37)

```
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(10) // 10 being number of simultaneous operations.

// Tasks in serial queues execute one at a time.
// Each task starting only after the preceding task has finished. 
// Serial queues are also known as private dispatch queues.

serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("imageProcessingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
for image in annotationImages {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) // block if 10 images downloading
    downloader.downloadAsync(image, ...) { // completion
          dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
          // handle annotation images or error
          // add downloaded annotation images to...
    }
  }
}
```

After that you count the remaining operations and implement a completion handler when they're finished. Or group operations etc.

```
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
dispatch_async(main_queue()) {...stuff...}
}
```

### Second option using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`

If you want to try `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` as suggested below [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) has an excellent tutorial.

`NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` are built on top of GCD. `NSOperation` adds a little extra overhead compared to GCD, but you can add dependency among various operations and re-use, cancel or suspend them.

As the RW page illustrates the code would look something like this. Use-case is different but this is the general idea without the recursion.

Operations.swift

```
class PendingOperations {
lazy var downloadsInProgress = [NSIndexPath:NSOperation]()
lazy var downloadQueue:NSOperationQueue = {
var queue = NSOperationQueue()
queue.name = "Download queue"
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
return queue
}()
}
```

Implement the method.

```
func startDownloadForMap(...params...){
if let downloadOperation = pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress... {
return
}

let downloader = ImageDownloader(...)

downloader.completionBlock = {
if downloader.cancelled {
  return
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.(do_your_thang)
  // ...code
})
}
pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress... = downloader
pendingOperations.downloadQueue.addOperation(downloader)
}
```

Comment: The logic described above is mostly correct, except for a small bug, i.e., the dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) should be moved inside the "for" loop, just above downloader.downloadAsync(image, ...)

However, instead of using GCD API, I would rather recommend the NSOperation and NSOperationQueue APIs for your particular problem here, specifically for the cancellability of NSOperation.

Comment: Code updated. Thanks for the correction. Good second option. `NSOperationQueue` itself is backed by GCD queue, though that’s a private implementation.